# Использование функции translate()

Tags: c#, xpath, htmlagilitypack

Решаю задачу сравнения двух чисел.

Пытаюсь применить функцию xpath `translate()` для этого(`<span>$1</span>`) html,чтобы убрать знак доллар. Делаю так: `//span/translate(.,'$','')` — xpath неверен

Ещё пытаюсь выставить условие `<=10`, но не знаю как сравнить полученный результат с 10. Пытаюсь делать так: `//span[translate(.,'$','')<=10]` — не работает.

Comment: Второе должно работать - http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=d109333b-45db-4f25-8835-e74a9a542211-xpath , а первое надо вот так записывать - `translate(//span,"$","")<=10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш второй xpath сделан совершенно верно. [**Тут**](http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=d109333b-45db-4f25-8835-e74a9a542211-xpath#.VtboxPmLQQ8) можно в этом убедиться

А  первый следует написать следующим образом

```
translate(//span,"$","")<=10
```